# Passing a password to next php page

Tags: php, database, passwords, phpmyadmin

Wondering if i could get some quick help!
creating a simple website and for administrator purposes i need to be able to access a page where i can upload and delete stuff from phpmyadmin database.
The thing im having trouble with is being able to send the password from the html page where it's input, to the next page where it's checked. So idealy i will start on "admin.html" which has a text box for the password. Then next page is "adminmenu.php." and adminmenu.php can only be accessed if the password matches the user of the database. (keep in mind the password is not stored in a table like alot of the other questions similar to this)

this is my form on admin.html (password box)

```
<form name="input" action="adminmenu.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Password: <input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

so isnt the password sent as "password" for the next page?

after that i just dont really know how to check it. This is like my unsure guess at it:

```
$handle = mysql_connect("localhost", "uMoviesRoot","password") or die ('Error:' .mysql_error())
mysql_select_db("movies");
```

thanks for any help guys!

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. It looks like you're still learning PHP, so now would be a *great* time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Okay, I think I understand what you want.  You have admin.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Blah</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="adminhandle.php" method="POST">
            Password: <input type="password" name="pass" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log on" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

adminhandle.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$handle = mysql_connect("localhost", "uMoviesRoot", "$_POST['pass']") or die ('Error:' .mysql_error())
mysql_select_db("movies");

if ($handle) $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
?>
```

adminmenu.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['logged_in']) {
    // show menu or whatever
} else {
    echo "Password failed!";
}
?>
```

---

Take a couple steps back and get a good resource to learn from.  I recommend [Larry Ullman's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321784073).

Comment: While you can shorten it to just the form and the last page, I feel that breaking it up like this will help you see what's going on.

Comment: so i can create another separate php file adminhandle.php that will determine if the password is correct? but then from there how does it know to go to adminmenu.php? and again thanks for your help as im pretty new

Comment: nvm. i get it. I'll just keep it as 2 files skip the middle one, but any tips on how i show the menu only if the session is logged in? is it as simple as putting my code under the if haha?

Answer (score 0):

The password is sent as

```
$_POST['password']
```

not 'password' or '$password'.

So if you want to use it to connect to mysql_connect, you need to do

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "uMoviesRoot", $_POST['password'])
```

But then you need to 'keep' the password for every new page you visit. You can store it in a session, but if it's on a shared hosting server it's not a great idea.

Comment: Thanks for your response so are you saying on my .html page i also need to send the password as $_POST["password"]?

Comment: No, he's saying use that in adminmenu.php

Comment: wait nvm it's is being sent as post durr, but when i change it to $_POST["password"] it still lets me type whatever i want for the password!

Comment: If you're asking to do validation on $_POST['password'] then you really need to read up on PHP and common methods of admin validation a bit more.

In any case, If you type in "whatever you want" the mysql_connect should reject invalid passwords - unless you're accepting all connections from localhost without validating the password?

Comment: What do you mean by that?  What are you expecting to happen and what *is actually* happening?

Comment: @KevinM1 what i want to happen is for if the password is correct to go to adminmenu.php and if incorrect it's either supposed to stay the go to the same page (adminmenu.php) but display that the password was incorrect.What is actually happening is no matter what i type in it is still granting me access to the page adminmenu.php .btw thanks for your help and patience, im still learning

Comment: well actually i guess it is working. The fact that im already on the page i want to display of the password is correct (and the same page i'll already be on if its wrong), i just need a way to display "password incorrect" if wrong _while hiding the rest of the page you see if it's a success_ .But if the password is correct display the page regularly

Comment: @erp take a look at my edited answer below.  Maybe that will make more sense.

Comment: any tips on how i show the menu only if the session is logged in? is it as simple as putting my code under the if haha?

Comment: @erp If the original question about the password has been answered, suggest closing this off. You're now asking additional questions about unrelated functionality (about how to display a message about failure).

Answer (score -1):

There are some ways for transmitting Data between some PHP scripts.

The easiest was ist to use Sessions.

at the beginning you have to do a

```
session_start();
```

and then you can use the $_SESSION array, that is user-specific.

So at least you have:

```
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION["password"] = $_POST["password"]; mysql_connect(..., $_SESSION["password"]);...?>
```

but beware of security!
There are many security risks if you make the password or any other string that is transmitted to MySQL directly accessible and don't parse it for SQL-Injections!

Comment: This is a classic form handling scenario.  While sessions would work, it's not really appropriate in this context.

Comment: the headline suggested passing information to next php script... well, he meant passing from html to php. at least he will save the password for the next page (I don't think it will be just one page) so using sessions will be the best choice)

Comment: Apologies, you were on the right track.  If you edit this answer, I can give an upvote